# Does the inverse-cube law for dipoles collapse into the inverse-square law for a 2-dimensional system?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Such as a piece of sheet-metal, or the mammalian cortex?

Comment: Can you build up a bit more on your question ? You should write up the model and define precisely (mathematically speaking) what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really how two-dimensional electrostatic systems work - even if you restrict charges to a surface, they still 'emit' electric field flux outside it. Instead, two-dimensional electrostatics actually describes three-dimensional systems with translational symmetry along one axis, so e.g. a point charge in 2D electrostatics corresponds in 3D to an infinitely long line charge; you can check easily that they have the same $\propto 1/r$ electric field.

And yes, within that formalism, electric dipoles (now represented by to infinitely strong line charges, at infinitely small separation) do have a $\propto 1/r^2$ dependence.